# What evidence do we have that disabled people became shamans in pre-historic times?

Tags: prehistory

Ian Crofton writes in *50 world history events you really need to know*, regarding division of labour in pre-historic hunter-gatherer societies:

> Before the coming of farming there was some division of labour. In hunter-gatherer societies the women usually did most of the gathering and the men most of the hunting, while certain individuals, sometimes with some form of disability, became shamans.

Because the book is a short synopsis for a layman audience, there isn't a citation for the evidence to support this claim.

My question is, **how do we know that some disabled people became shamans in pre-historic, hunter-gatherer societies?**

Comment: A simple google search reveal multiple sources. (a few of which are credible).

Comment: We have absolutely no evidences on that subject. Maybe, if prehistoric archeology will have much more found graves, we could answer the question, but all "evidences" on the subject are purely speculative. And BTW, it could be a great fallacy by itself, to think that there existed anything common in behaviour for all prehistoric communities, for all prehistoric times. Maybe only, the most base things, as sex, death, birth, food, drink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source might be referring to the potential link between schizophrenia, or more specifically milder versions of it, and religiosity. Cases of "possession" and "inner voices" attributed to gods and spirits that eventually led to organized religion could indeed have been mild cases of schizophrenia. The theory originates from [Paul Radin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Radin) in the 1930s.

Interesting lecture on the topic: [Dr. Robert Sapolsky on Biological Underpinnings of Religiosity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WwAQqWUkpI). He discusses precisely the topic you're wondering about around 12:00. There's also an interesting bit on the link between ritualism and OCD around 30:00.

Comment: Any scientific hypothesis must have a proposition of an experiment how it could be checked and confronted. If it hasn't such proposition, it is a pure speculation. If a hypothesis had passed several such checks, made by independent scientisists, it could change its name to "theory".  And practically 99% of behavioral anthropology is such speculation. The very use of the word "theory" for the mentioned thoughts is absolutely incorrect. It was not even ever a hypothesis, let alone theory. Behavioral anthropology has same "science"rights as astrology.

Comment: @Gangnus: Faire enough, but FYI experimental psychology has been studying behavior patterns related to religiosity and cult groups for a while now, and has primarily been doing so using reproducible experiments. Comically, [an anecdotal observation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Prophecy_Fails) described how, in the aftermath of a failed doomsday prophecy, members of a cult split in two groups: one stepped away in disbelief, while the other went from reclusive to enthusiastic proselytes.

Comment: Hi, Denis. "reproducible experiments" is not enough. The correct testing of a hypothesis must include: 1) checkable questions for which hypothesis will say "yes" 2) questions, answers for which must be "no". 3) questions, answers for which must be pre-known, and fail in these answers mean fail of the hypothesis. 4) These experiments should check the hypothesis in really harsh way, and for all thinkable fails. (#4 - is the demand for theory)

Comment: Have you read at least ONCE the history of a behavioral anthropology hypothesis that had ONE pre-prepared question of #3 kind that was checked AFTERWARDS? Even more, could you imagine such check for the proposed hypothesis?

Comment: Biological anthropology and Genetic anthropology - they are OK.  They are sciences for their hypothesis can be checked and were checked many times. Many of them were thrown off because they haven't passed these checks. That is the sign of the real science. Experimental psychology nowadays can work honestly, too. But the question does not belong to them.

Comment: And don't forget, that psychique problems differs in different societies. So, the contemporary experiments does not even allow us to think that prehistoric people COULD use people with problem psychique as shamans. Or that they HAD shamans. You can check only behaviour that leaves traces in real materials. For example - "blond men never made children with blond women"- that could be checked by some genetic research. " "they used spears" - you can find spears or their traces. Or not find them. But we have not a single grave that is proven one of a shaman.

Comment: @Gangnus: "ONE pre-prepared question of #3 kind that was checked AFTERWARDS?" That's precisely what experimental social psychology is about: you build an experiment to test a hypothesis, and validate (or invalidate it). See e.g. the Milgram experiment, which was built to test the excuse laid out by WW2 war criminals at Nuremberg ("was just following orders") and incidentally surprised the researcher and the community so much that it went on to get reproduced in many different countries.

Comment: What your example has in common with the behavioral anthropology? What do you answer to? I have said that experimental psychology works honestly nowadays. But the question belongs to OTHER science.

Comment: @Gangnus: You asked for an example for hypothesis testing in an experiment; I gave you one of the more canonical ones I'm aware of. And it's a relevant one at that: it's about your average Joe mindlessly (or not so mindlessly) following authoritative figures - including religious ones - _because he must_. But anyway, this discussion is clearly getting nowhere, so let's leave it at that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63125/discussion-between-gangnus-and-denis-de-bernardy).